# Netty 4.x Http Multipart Package

Tags: netty

Where is the io.netty.handler.codec.http.multipart package in the latest Netty 4 Alpha releases?

The all-in-one JAR file netty-4.0.0.Alpha5.jar doesn't have the package, and the code is not in the master branch in github...

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not ported yet... It's on the to-do list and should be done before final is cut.